# css files are not loaded if you load from"/"

Tags: go

I found a solution, but it only works if the path is specified

```golang
fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./html"))
http.Handle("/html/", http.StripPrefix("/html/", fileServer))
```

When I try to do it from "/" nothing comes out
including

```golang
http.handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./html/")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for yourself, below program will test both cases.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "text/tabwriter"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    srv1 := &http.Server{
        Addr: "localhost:9090",
    }
    go func() {
        mux := http.NewServeMux()
        fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./html"))
        mux.Handle("/", fileServer)
        srv1.Handler = mux
        srv1.ListenAndServe()
    }()
    srv2 := &http.Server{
        Addr: "localhost:9091",
    }
    go func() {
        mux := http.NewServeMux()
        fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./html"))
        mux.Handle("/html/", http.StripPrefix("/html/", fileServer))
        srv2.Handler = mux
        srv2.ListenAndServe()
    }()

    srvs := []*http.Server{srv1, srv2}

    urls := []string{
        "http://%v/index.css",
        "http://%v/html/index.css",
    }

    // u := fmt.Sprintf("http://%v/html/index.css", srv.Addr)
    w := new(tabwriter.Writer)
    w.Init(os.Stdout, 8, 8, 0, '\t', 0)

    defer fmt.Println()
    defer w.Flush()

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "\n %s\t%s\t", "URL", "Response")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "\n %s\t%s\t", "----", "----")

    for _, srv := range srvs {
        for _, f := range urls {
            <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 200)
            u := fmt.Sprintf(f, srv.Addr)
            res, err := http.Get(u)
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }
            var out bytes.Buffer
            io.Copy(&out, res.Body)
            res.Body.Close()
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "\n %s\t%s\t", u, fmt.Sprintf("%q", out.String()))
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs

```
$ go run .

 URL                                    Response        
 ----                                   ----            
 http://localhost:9090/index.css        "OK\n"          
 http://localhost:9090/html/index.css   "404 page not found\n"  
 http://localhost:9091/index.css        "404 page not found\n"  
 http://localhost:9091/html/index.css   "OK\n"
```

It works by manually creating two [HTTP servers](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Server) [that listens](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Server.ListenAndServe) on distinct local addresses. Each server gets a different [mux](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux) setup. Then it [GET](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Get)s both server with multiple different URLs. The fetch is retried multiple times until no error occurs to account for the un-syncrhonized servers startup before proceeding. The output is formatted with the help of a [TabWriter](https://pkg.go.dev/text/tabwriter).